# Selecting input type text value with jQuery: bad behavior in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a code that selects the value of an input type text when the `click` event is triggered over the relative element, so i'm expecting that the value to be ***always*** selected as long as the user keeps on clicking over the input element. And this is what correctly happens in Firefox and Edge. Unfortunately in Chrome the value turns from selected to unselected (and vice versa) each time i click on the element. Is this a bug? Is there a workaround i can use?

Now, this is the HTML

```
<div id="feedback">
    <input value="http://36k.it/qHx26" readonly="readonly">
</div>
```

This is the jQuery:

```
$('#feedback').on('click', 'input', function () { $(this).select() });
```

I'm googling since this morning with no success...

Comment: try $('#feedback INPUT').on('click', function () { $(this).select() });

Comment: @dxcorzo no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inconsistency you are seeing is because there is not a well defined, or standard way to implement the select method that is accepted by each browser. Because of this the select method's behavior changes from browser to browser.  Here is a good link to help explain what you can expect from the select method across browsers.

[Select Method Behavior](http://www.impressivewebs.com/input-select-correct-behaviour/)

Comment: This is sad. Thanks for your answer anyway.